# accessing STIX data with Perl

Tags: perl

on python there are a stix client library **https://github.com/oasis-open/cti-taxii-client)** for accessing STIX **(https://stixproject.github.io/)** servers

what is the recommended/equivlant library to access stix data using Perl any help ?

Answer (score 1):

1. There seems to be none - check [cpan](https://metacpan.org/search?size=500&q=stix)
2. Your link to stix is outdated - check https://oasis-open.github.io/cti-documentation/